# I'm trying to make a message system that can theoretically send messages from on batch file to another while keeping both open

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, message-system

I have some code already done some code for the sender.bat and receiver.bat but the problem is, that when I send the message from the sender.bat it calls the receiver.bat and at which point I have two problems:
1)The sender.bat closes (and I want that to stay open so I can send further messages) and receiver.bat opens (which is what I want) but when it opens it brings with it the second problem.
2)It keeps repeating the same (the first) message

So I'll just give you the code and hope someone figures out what i have done wrong

Sender.bat:

```
@echo off
title "Message Sender"
set /p name=Username:

:x
set /p mes=Message:

set nmes=%name% Says: %mes%
call receiver.bat %nmes%
goto x
```

and the receiver.bat:

```
@echo off

:x
echo %1
echo %1>>conversationlogger.txt
pause
goto x
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Once you open up a new CMD window, it will inherit all environmental variables in the CMD window from which it was called. However, from there on the environmental variables are no longer synced, disabling any sending of information via the environmental variables. Sending data as parameters to a script can only be done once, at the start. The best solution for accomplishing your goal would be to use `REG ADD`to create a new Windows registry key, and use this key to pass data between two CMD windows. (Using `REG QUERY`).

Comment: @user504882: This don't works either. The new variables set by `REG ADD` are NOT updated in the other _active_ CMD window, but until a _new_ CMD window is started after that...

Answer (score 0):

1. `Sender.bat` doesn't close. It waits until `receiver.bat` finishes - which will not happen because of a endless loop.
2. `receiver.bat` doesn't get another message to display, therefore repeats the message (to be exact: the first word of it) in an endless loop.

remove `goto x` from `receiver.bat` to solve the endless loop. And change `%1` to `%*` to get the complete message, not the first word only.

**EDIT** now I understand you want to have two separate windows. Sadly, there is no built-in-way for communication between separate cmd windows, but it can be done "extern", for example via a text file.

Sender.bat

```
@echo off
title "Message Sender"
start "Receiver" receiver.bat
set /p name=Username:
title "Message Sender: %name%
echo "<<%name% joined>>">%name%sended.txt
>>"conversationlogger.txt" echo %date% %time%: echo "<<%name% joined>>"
:x
set "_message=<nothing>"
set /p mes=Message:
echo "%name% Says: %_message%">%name%_sended.txt
if /i "%_message%"=="quitme" (
  title "Sender leaving"
  echo "<<%name% left>>">%name%_sended.txt
  for /f %%n in ('tasklist /v ^|find /c "Message Sender"') do (
    if "%%n"=="0" echo "<<last member left>>">%name%_sended.txt
  )
  exit
)
goto :x
```

Receiver.bat

```
@echo off
echo checking for running receiver...
tasklist /v | find "Message Receiver" && exit
cls
title "Message Receiver"

:x
for %%a in (*_sended.txt) do (
  call :say "%%~a" & del "%%a"
)
ping -n 1 -w 200 192.168.254.254 >nul
goto :x

:say
<%1 set /p "_message="
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%i in ('set _message') do (
  echo %time:~0,8%: %%~i
  >>"conversationlogger.txt" echo %date% %time%: %%~i 
  if "%%~i"=="<<last member left>>" ( pause & exit )  
)
goto :eof
```

I have included a few features, that came to my mind. Keep, what you find useful, delete the rest. Feel free to ask, if you don't understand parts of the code or why I choosed that way to do it.

You can have more than one sender, but there will be only one receiver (per computer; I didn't test it, but it should be possible to chat over different PC's via network, when using a common network drive for `*_sended.txt`)

Just start the sender, it starts the receiver itself (which checks, if another receiver is running and exits, if yes)

Comment: I think it would be better to put the message between quotes and use `%~1`

Answer (score 0):

The only way to "keep both files open" is executing they simultaneously, that is, via `start` command or (as the "natural" way for this case), connected via a pipe.

**sender.bat**:

```
@echo off
title "Message Sender"
set /p name=Username: > CON

:x
set "mes="
set /p mes=Message: > CON
if not defined mes goto end

set nmes=%name% Says: %mes%
echo %nmes%
goto x

:end
echo Conversation ends > CON
```

**receiver.bat**:

```
@echo off

:x
set "msg="
set /P "msg="
if not defined msg exit /B

echo %msg%
echo %msg%>>conversationlogger.txt
goto x
```

Execute these files in this (obvious) way:

```
sender | receiver
```

**EDIT**: I added the output of an example session:

```
C:\> sender | receiver
Username: Antonio
Message: This is the first message
Antonio Says: This is the first message
Message: The second line
Antonio Says: The second line
Message: Last message...
Antonio Says: Last message...
Message:
Conversation ends

C:\> type conversationlogger.txt
Antonio Says: This is the first message
Antonio Says: The second line
Antonio Says: Last message...

C:\>
```