# How do I create an update function in Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create an update function that works just after the user is prompted to type into the "ChatBox" so that other users on my school network can type and all other users can see it without having to restart the program or typing space to reload the .txt file

here is the code I have written so far;

```
:enter
cls
type cblog.txt
echo.
set /p text=
echo %text% >> cblog.txt
goto enter
```

Comment: `batch` has no support for inter-process-communication. Maybe you want to use a [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35683551/im-trying-to-make-a-message-system-that-can-theoretically-send-messages-from-on/35684010#35684010)

Comment: I would suggest you Google search Batch Chat.  You aren't the first person to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I like this topic, so I wrote a fully working prototype:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1" equ "" echo You must give your username as parameter & goto :EOF

set "user=%~1"
set "now=%time%"
echo %now%: User %user% entered the chat room>> msgQueue.txt
call :chatRoom 3< msgQueue.txt
goto :EOF


:chatRoom

rem Omit previous messages
:omitMsg
   set /P "msg=" <&3
if "%msg:~0,12%" neq "%now%:" goto omitMsg
echo %msg%
echo/

echo Press S to send a message or eXit to end
echo/
:msgLoop

rem Check for new messages received
:showMsg
   set "msg="
   set /P "msg=" <&3
   if not defined msg goto send
   echo %msg%
goto :showMsg

rem Check to send a new message
:send
ver > NUL
choice /C SNX /N /T 3 /D N > NUL
if errorlevel 3 goto end
if errorlevel 2 goto msgLoop

rem Send a message
echo -----------------------------------
set /P "msg=Message: "
echo -----------------------------------
echo %user%: %msg% >> msgQueue.txt
goto msgLoop

:end
echo %time%: User %user% leaved the chat room>> msgQueue.txt
```

The response time may be adjusted in `/T 3` parameter of `choice` command: shorter times makes the chat more responsive, but it consume more CPU time.

Below is an image that show a test with four users in the Chat Room:

[image: ChatRoom with four users]

Comment: the program seems to close as soon as i opened it i think it may be because you have stated "goto :EOF" but there is nothing in your code under the name EOF

Comment: @callum - `goto :eof` is a system command that means "go to the end of the script."

Comment: Do you know why you code seems to be closing as soon as it opens do I need to download something for the code to work

Comment: The program works correctly here; see my edit. I suggest you to first open several cmd.exe Windows and execute the Batch file from there (_not_ via a double click in the explorer). Did you read the `You must give your username as parameter` message? This means execute the Batch file this way: `test.bat YourNameHere` _from the command-line_.